# Should subclasses call the designated initializer in the immediate super class?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've seen some sample code which has got me wondering about calling the designated initializer in the super classes. Say I have some code this:

```
@interface NewTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
}
@end

@implementation NewTableViewCell 
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
return self;
}
@end
```

Note that `initWithFrame` is the designated initializer for `UIView`, not `UITableView`. Should this code always be calling `[UITableViewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]`, or does it depend on the coder's intent?

Comment: You mean [UITableviewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When subclassing, the guideline is that the designated initializer has to call its super class' designated  initializer.

Another guideline is that the subclass needs to override the superclass' designated initializer to call the new designated initializer.

If `UITableViewCell` follows this guideline (and it does; I tested with the help of a category), it overrides its superclass' designated initializer (`UIView`'s `initWithFrame:`) to call the new designated initializer (`initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`). Therefore, if you call `initWithFrame:` on `UITableViewCell` it will call `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, which in turn will call `initWithFrame:` on `super` (`UIView`).

Therefore, it will need an additional method call but it will eventually go through `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Again, the best practice is that the designated initializer has to call the super class' designated initializer and any other initializer that isn't the designated initializer has to call the designated initializer. From ["The Designated Initializer"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-106376):

> **General principle**: The designated initializer in a class must, through a message to super, invoke the designated initializer in a superclass.
>
> Designated initializers are chained to each other through messages to super, while other initialization methods are chained to designated initializers through messages to self.

Comment: If the designated initializer has to invoke the designated initializer of the super class, what are the other initializers supposed to do? Suppose I decided that the designated initializer of my view would be a method called initWithPoint:(CGPoint) point. What would the implementation of initWithFrame be? Would it invoke the designated initializer with a default Point? Would it do something else?

Comment: @j0k other initializers are supposed to call the designated initializer. You are not forced to provide a `initWithFrame` method, but if you do, I guess you could call your designated initializer with a default point. If you don't provide the method and you init a new instance via `initWithFrame` (defined in a superclass), your designated initializer will eventually get called and the instance will be properly initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anything special we need to do to designate an initializer as a designated intializer other than perhaps mentioning this in the documentation?

Comment: @j0k No. Any initializer can be the designated initializer, it just needs to be clearly documented. However, the designated initializer is typically the one with most parameters (but not always).

Answer (score 1):

I agree it depends on the coders attempt but the coder should always try and use the designated initializer. Think about initializers you may have written, they probably do additional work for your object to be in a usable or desired state. If you are overriding an initializer like you are doing in your example you should call the overridden initializer as well. If that was a custom init method then you would want to call the designated initializer because for `UITableViewCell`'s that is the only way to set the reuseIdentifier publicly.

```
//Override initWithFrame
//Fine although it may not (should not) get called for a UITableViewCell
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

//Design a custom initializer to gather parameters for supers default initializer
-(id)initWithCustomObject:(id)object style:(UI..Style)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)rid {
    //This should call initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```