# NSWindowController initialization warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, designated-initializer

I am developing a document-based app. I am using a dedicated window controller for the document window, and calling the `-[NSDocument makeWindowControllers]` method.

My window controller is initialized like this:

```
- (instancetype) init
{
    if (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"Document" owner:self]) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

Here, `@"Document"` is the .xib file containing the main document window that was created with the project.

The rationale here is that, this window controller is **always** initialized with this type of window, so the parameter is both hard-coded and hidden away inside the implementation of `-init` (while also conveniently setting the window owner to `self`).

So, the side that instantiates the window controller (in my case, the document class) doesn't need to worry about which nib to use and can just call `-init`.

The problem is, I am breaking the designated initializer chain and Xcode complains with these warnings:

> Semantic Issue  Method override for the designated initializer of the
>   superclass '-initWithCoder:' not found.
>
> Semantic Issue Designated initializer missing a 'super' call to a
>   designated initializer of the super class.
>
> Semantic Issue  Method override for the designated initializer of the
>   superclass '-initWithWindow:' not found.
>
> Semantic Issue  Designated initializer invoked a non-designated
>   initializer.

I would switch the call to `-initWithWindowNibName:owner:` with one to `-initWithWindow:` (and after that, set the owner manually, I guess?); but I don't know how to create an `NSWindow` directly from a nib (or if this is the right thing to do).

**EDIT:** I just discovered that the warnings are being triggered only because I labeled `-init` as `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` in my interface. I can remove that label and the warnings go away, but `-init` **is** my de-facto designated initializer so I would rather keep it.

Comment: You read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030354/should-subclasses-call-the-designated-initializer-in-the-immediate-super-class)?

Comment: No; I will now. Thank you.

Comment: I did and I couldn't translate it to a succinct answer.  Would need to play with it in XCode to see what makes it happy, so by all means answer this yourself.